# css - shrink a parent div to fit one child's width and constrain the width of the other child

Tags: css

Say, a parent div has two child divs, one containing text, the other containing an image of known (but variable) width & height.

I would like

- the width of the first child (image-containing) div to shrink to fit the width of the image (this i can do)
- the parent div (of unspecified width) to shrink to fit the width of the image-containing div (this is ok too)
- the text-containing second child div (also of unspecified width) to match the parent div's width irrespective of the quantity of text it contains (this is where it gets tricky).

I have a working version that does what I want *until* the quantity of text in the second child pushes the parent div's width wider than that of the image.

Here's my code:

css:

```
#container{border:1px solid #f00;display:inline-block;}
#child1{border:1px solid #0f0;}
#child2{border:1px solid #00f;}
img {border:1px solid #000;}
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="child1"><img src="//www.google.com/logos/2012/Teachers_Day_Alt-2012-hp.jpg" width="300" height="116"></div>
<div id="child2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

and here's a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BmbAS/1/

you can see where it's going wrong by clicking the 'lengthen/shorten text' link to increase the quantity of text

**tldr - i want all the divs to be the same width which is equal to the width of the image**

ps. modern browser solution only necessary

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See [this edited version](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/qs8GJ/) of your jsFiddle.

Here's what's added to the CSS:

```
#container {
    display: table-cell;
}
#child1 {
    display: table-row;
    width: 1px;
}
#child2 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: fantastic. that does the trick! i should have known the solution would include table display as it's a table to div translation problem I was truing to solve ;)

Answer (score 8):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12747183/6543935) provided by @Chris leads me to the following, great solution of my case, where I need to fit the container div only to the first child element (and leave the rest child elements to auto fit to the container's width):

```css
.wrapper { /* optional container */
    width: fit-content;  /* essential prop */

    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 16px auto;
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.container {
    width: fit-content;  /* essential prop */
    display: table;  /* essential prop */
}

.inner-primary {
    display: block;  /* essential prop */

    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.inner-rest {
    display: table-caption;  /* essential prop */
    caption-side: bottom;  /* essential prop */

    margin-top: 1rem;
    padding: 0 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner-primary"><div style="width:200px; border:1px dotted #ccc; border-radius:4px; padding: 4px;">This is the main element that drives the width of the container.</div></div>
    <div class="inner-rest">This is the first of the rest divs that fit automatically to the container...</div>
    <div class="inner-rest">This is the second element...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty impressive and perfect for my use! The one caveat is that the captions technically fall outside of the container, so applying backgrounds, borders, shadows, etc to the container won't 'wrap around' the caption, but for some designs this won't be an issue.

Comment: Hi, @kevlarr. You can wrap the "container" DIV within another DIV with style like this: `style="width: fit-content;  padding: 0.5em; border: 1px solid; margin: auto;"`... etc.

Comment: Whoa I thought I'd tried that and the caption was still spilling out, so to speak. Not sure what I was doing wrong. Thanks @pa4080, this is one of the most useful tricks I've seen to control widths - for me, I was using an `<img>` and didn't want to assign static dimensions to any element, and this was perfect.

Comment: Hi, @kevlarr, just in case and further reuse I've updated the answer :)

Answer (score -2):

If you're willing to use a little javascript (jQuery in this example), you could set the width of the text div with the width of the image div.

Try adding `$("#child2").css({'width': $('#child1').width()});` to the end of the JS in your fiddle, or check out the fork here: http://jsfiddle.net/VXEMu/

Comment: ah, i forgot to mention (i knew i'd forget something) that i was looking for a css-only solution.

Comment: for something so simple you really shouldn't use scripting.