# Make child div text content NOT expand its parent fixed-positioned div's width

Tags: css, html

I am working on kind of a popup. Its structure is very simple and is as follows:

```
<div class = "popup">
    <div class = "upper">
        <img src = "http://www.tapeta-mis-galazki-koala.na-pulpit.com/pokaz_obrazek.php?adres=mis-galazki-koala&rozdzielczosc=128x128" />
    </div>
    <div class = "description">This is a very interesting description of what you can see above.</div>
</div>
```

with styles of

```
.popup
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px; 
    top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
.popup .upper {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.popup .upper img {
    display: block;
}
```

and here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/de6fr/) with the code applied.

As you can see, the `div.popup` is positioned as fixed to the `body`.

What I want to achieve is to make the `div.description` *NOT* extend its parent `div.popup` width when it contains much text, instead it should wrap the text to be multilined and be of width of the `div.popup`. The `div.popup` width should be determined by the `div.upper` width and its content. In other words I mean to have `div.description`'s width *AT MOST* of the `div.upper`'s width, regardless to its (`div.description` text content).

### EDIT

There's this little difficulty: **the image content is not static and may be dynamically changed so the width is not constant.**

Is that even possible to achieve that with CSS?

Comment: it looks like you want to figure out the width of `image` then add that width to fixed element `.popup`

Comment: It is exactly what I forgot to mention: the image content and its width may vary :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/de6fr/1/ - a basic example of how to fix

---

You're basically using popup as a container, which means that if you want to retain its width, that's what you have to work on. I used the `max-width` property with `.popup` like this:

```
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px; 
    top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    display: table;
    width: 1px;
}
.popup > div { 
    display: table-row;
}

.popup .upper {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
}
.popup .upper img {
    display: block;
}
```

---

**Update - Flexible**

http://jsfiddle.net/de6fr/4/

The fix for making it flexible is to use a [CSS hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747045/css-shrink-a-parent-div-to-fit-one-childs-width-and-constrain-the-width-of-th?rq=1), which basically changes the nature of the element to a `table`

The nature of CSS (*cascading* style sheets) means that it's pretty hard to get a parent DIV to take the size of a child div without some crazy ideas involved. However, there's nothing preventing a "table" with a really small width doing that, as per this code:

```
.popup
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px; 
    top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    display: table;
    width: 1px;
}
.popup .upper {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    display: table-row;
}
.popup .upper img {
    display: block;
}
.popup .description {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: It would be highly appreciated as I forgot of the most important thing that I have just added to my question with an edit. I hope it is still somehow possible to make it work the way I want.

Comment: Did not get notified about your edit, that is a shame. Still this is really impressive how well it works :D yet is it something that people call 'cross-browser'? What am I doing is targeting multiple browsers, including older ones.

Comment: No problem! Tables are the oldest HTML tag known to man, so I guess it's a question of whether older browsers support display: table in CSS. Here is [some info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) about this:

`Note: The values "inline-table", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.`

Comment: Then I can say it is enough as I am denying ie7-and-lower users. Thank you for your help again :D

Comment: No problem buddy! If you need any more help, please just ask!

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS property to your popup class and Give it a width

```
.popup
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px; 
    top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    overflow:scroll;
    width:400px;
}
```

Comment: The scrolls do not convince me as it needs to look elegant. And there's this thing I forgot to say which is that the image is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the width for fixed element so add some width to your fiexed element

```
.popup
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px; 
    top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/de6fr/2/)